# PhpStorm how to change style.css timestamp if file is changed

Tags: php, caching, phpstorm, browser-cache

As a cache busting technique, I add a timestamp as a parameter on my CSS file and change it whenever I change my stylesheet: **style.css?t={TIMESTAMP}**

I'm currently doing this manually, but I wish to add it to JavaScript files, images etc. Is there an automatic way in PhpStorm that detects a file change and then updates the timestamp?

Comment: why not use a version control tool like Git or SVN instead?

Comment: not sure what you mean, I'm using version control but if I update the style.css and deploy it to the server, I would like to "force" users to download the new version.

Comment: PhpStorm has no such functionality. Usually such stuff is handled at backend by Asset Management scripts/libraries -- often part of/used by frameworks (e.g. Assetic in Symfony -- not used since 2.9 though)

Comment: @LazyOne thank you! Using your comment I figured out my Framework (CakePHP) supports this functionality.